# exclude rows with pattern matching in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data frame with few columns.
How to filter out rows (from one of the column) which have the pattern ADD in the values

Few Values from the col are IADDR,IADDX, IADDV

I tried `filter(!str_detect(column,'\\<ADD\\>'))` but nothing is getting filtered

Thanks in advance

Comment: Get rid of the `\<` and `\>`. Just `your_data %>% filter(!str_detect(column,'ADD'))`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `grep` from `base R`

```
subset(df1, grepl('ADD', column))
```